# How do you grab a headline from a blog/article like techmeme?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a creating a type of news aggregator and I would like to create a program(Python) that correctly detects the headline and displays it.  How would I go about doing this?  Is this a machine learning problem?

I would appreciate any articles or books that would point me in the right direction.

My past attempts have included BeautifulSoup and Requests module. Any other open source models I should check out?

Thank you, 
Fernando

Comment: Most headlines are in `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc. tags. Once you scrape all of those headlines, you could try using machine learning to further narrow down the potential headlines, even possibly categorize them with assisted learning by having users validate the choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct way to scrape a web page requires human learning - look at the page, decide what you think are headlines, find out how they are tagged, and then look for those tags using a parser like BeautifulSoup.  For example, the level 1 headlines on Techmeme currently are labeled:

```
<DIV CLASS="ii">
```

and the level 2 headlines are:

```
<STRONG CLASS="L1">
```

After your program fetches the page and matches the tags you're interested in, see if they identify what you're looking for.  If some headlines are missed, add additional tags to your search list.  If you get false positives (hits on links that aren't headlines), weeding them out will require extra page-dependent logic.  There is no magic to reverse engineering, just grunt work and testing and periodic revalidation to be sure the webmaster hasn't switched things up on you.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit I find that this works best:

Use BeautifuSoup and Requests module

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

if soup.findAll('title'):
  title = soup.find('title')
  print title.renderContents()
```

What results is title text that should be cleaned up a bit using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be much easer with parsing their RSS\Atom feeds. Google easily delivers these links http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries and http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Atomisator/1.3

But those are pure XML, so you could use built-in [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) and XML([DOM](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) or [SAX](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html)) libraries

Comment: Alot of the sites dont have RSS/Atom feed. Thanks for the suggestion though.